# PHP Remove Everything After Character and Stop Before Character

Tags: php

My string:

```
$string = '/my-picture-gallery-1000x2000.jpg';
```

I need to remove everything after the last occurrence of "-" (including "-") in the string and stop at the "." in the string.

So the output should read as:

> /my-picture-gallery.jpg

but I need it to stop and keep everything after the "."

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: $string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "-")); but I need it to stop and keep everything after the "."

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question itself. Additionally, check whether `strripos` can help you

Comment: substr doesn’t “stop” anywhere in between. But if you managed to use that to get the part before the last `-`, then you should be able to figure out how to get everything after the (last) `.` as well, and then simply concatenate the two …

Comment: `preg_replace('/^(.*)-.*(\.[a-z]+)$/', "$1$2")` ?

Comment: The code I provided was just an example. That's why I did not include it in my original post as it does not achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be able to use PHP's [strstr](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) in-built function in combination with [str_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to get the result you're after

```
$string = '/my-picture-gallery-1000x2000.jpg';
echo str_replace(strrchr($string, '-'), '', $string) . strstr($string, '.');
```

That would leave you with:

> /my-picture-gallery.jpg

Slightly more readable version

```
$string = '/my-picture-gallery-1000x2000.jpg';

$dimensions = strrchr($string, '-');
$extension = strrchr($string, '.');

$image = str_replace($dimensions, '', $string) . $extension;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '/my-picture-gallery-1000x2000.jpg';
echo substr($string,0,strrpos($string,'-')) . substr($string,strrpos($string,'.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use *explode()* function. It returns array of strings. Just choose part or parts of string and combine them in one string.
More about *explode()* function at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$string = '/my-picture-gallery-1000x2000.jpg';

$ext= strstr($string, '.');
$dash=strrpos($string,'-');

$filename= substr($string, 0 ,$dash);

echo $filename.$ext;
```

In a short form , you can use :

```
$filename = substr($string, 0 ,strrpos($string,'-')).strstr($string, '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(false !== $pos = strrpos($string, '-'))
  $s = substr($string, 0, $pos);
```

First check if the needle is in the heystack using the reverse search. Then get the string from start up to the found position.

According to your edit a regular expression would be appropriate. This has also the advantage that it can handle UTF8 file pathes.

```
$new_name = preg_match('~^(.*)-[^-.]*(\..*)$~u', $string, $matches)
  ? $matches[1].$matches[2]
  : $string
;
```